# Is there a way to preserve formatting when outputing to a label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have some user input that I am outputting to a label.

I have used HTML.Encode in order to show the input in the way the user entered it (ignoring  as a html tag).

However, I have noticed that the user input like New Line are not using in the label. It's simply displayed as white space.

I've done this

```
                msg.Text = msg.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

which seems to now be displaying the right input.

Is that the best way to do this? Or is there like a common method that can convert newLines, tabs, etc. all of the invisible formatting things into HTML tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any other way.  What I usually do (in case you have a single "\n" or a "\r\n" combo) is replace all "\r\n" first, then any single "\n" last.

```
lbl.Text = lbl.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />").Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

For tabs you can use 4 non-breaking spaces.:

```
lbl.Text = lbl.Text.Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
```

To preserve any spacing (as html will aggregate multiple continuous spaces into a single space) use:

```
lbl.Text = lbl.Text.Replace("  ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;")//Replace every 2-space pair.
```

Remember to Encode your text first before adding in markup like <br /> that you intentionally want to render.

You could also use a TextBox, set it's MultiLine property to "true" and Enabled to "false" if you want to display the information with the original carriage returns without resorting to inserting markup.  I think the label is the best choice though.

Comment: thanks mate, I was looking for a framework method which I dont think there is, so I've put all those into my own helper method.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, just use a Multiline Textbox instead of label.